# DMA not enabled on old hardware

Tags: kernel, hard-drive

While working on an old hardware where Ubuntu is installed I noticed using top that a huge amount of CPU time was spent waiting for IO operations (network data transfer was in progress). I therefore checked for DMA state using this command:

```
sudo hdparm -d /dev/sdb2

/dev/sdb2:
 HDIO_GET_DMA failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Does this mean the device is not using DMA?
I also tried to retrieve information about the hardware and got this:

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb2

/dev/sdb2:

ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       WDC WD1600JB-00GVA0                     
        Serial Number:      WD-WCAL91665091
        Firmware Revision:  08.02D08
Standards:
        Supported: 6 5 4 
        Likely used: 8
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       4092    65535
        heads           16      1
        sectors/track   63      63
        --
        CHS current addressable sectors:    4128705
        LBA    user addressable sectors:   66055248
        LBA48  user addressable sectors:  312581808
        Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:      152627 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:      160041 MBytes (160 GB)
        cache/buffer size  = 8192 KBytes (type=DualPortCache)
Capabilities:
        LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
        Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, with device specific minimum
        R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
        Recommended acoustic management value: 128, current value: 254
        DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 *udma5 
             Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
        PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
             Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
        Enabled Supported:
           *    SMART feature set
                Security Mode feature set
           *    Power Management feature set
           *    Write cache
           *    Look-ahead
           *    Host Protected Area feature set
           *    WRITE_BUFFER command
           *    READ_BUFFER command
           *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
                SET_MAX security extension
                Automatic Acoustic Management feature set
           *    48-bit Address feature set
           *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
           *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
           *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
           *    SMART error logging
           *    SMART self-test
           *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
           *    SCT Long Sector Access (AC1)
           *    SCT LBA Segment Access (AC2)
           *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
           *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
           *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
Security: 
                supported
        not     enabled
        not     locked
        not     frozen
        not     expired: security count
        not     supported: enhanced erase
HW reset results:
        CBLID- above Vih
        Device num = 1 determined by the jumper
Checksum: correct
```

It is my understanding from this that DMA should be supported. Why am I getting that error and is it unusual that top shows values higher than 90% for "iowait" operations when two network transfers are running?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same message you do on two very different computers on 10.04 and 12.04 respectively. Adding making `-d` `-d1` says it is turning it on, but I suspect the messages tells us it isn't really effective.

I'm getting good disk access, however.

I once had trouble with slow disk response and, if I recall correctly, it was because DMA wasn't working. The cause was a bad ribbon cable that had been manipulated one time too many so it had a broken control lead used for DMA. Replacing the ribbon cable greatly increased performance.

In my case I saw a warning message at boot time that went away once I replaced the cable. I suggest you look at /var/log/syslog for any suspicious looking messages about your disk adapter or drive.